# JSON encoding for Flash Player 11 and AIR 3.0

Tags: json, actionscript-3, air

I have the following code:

thinkGearSocket = new Socket();

```
      var configuration : Object = new Object();
      configuration["enableRawOutput"] = true;
      configuration["format"] = "Json";
      thinkGearSocket.connect("127.0.0.1", 13854);
      thinkGearSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, dataHandler);
      thinkGearSocket.writeUTFBytes(JSON.encode(configuration));
```

It works for flash player 10 but for flash player 11 I get an error saying:

> 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method encode though a reference with static type flash.net:socket

I had the same error for the decoding with this:

```
private function dataHandler(e : ProgressEvent){
      //read data from the socket
      var packetString : String = thinkGearSocket.readUTFBytes(thinkGearSocket.bytesAvailable);
      thinkGearSocket.flush();

      //split the data into an array
      var packets : Array = packetString.split(/\r/);
      var data:Object;
      //iterate through array elements
      for each (var packet:String in packets){
        //sometimes the packet is empty
        if(packet != "") {
          try {
            data = JSON.decode(packet);
            //trace(packet);
          } catch ( jError: JSONParseError) {
              // do exception handling here
              label1.text = jError.text;

          }
```

But I changed:

```
data = JSON.decode(packet);
```

to:

```
data = JSON.parse(packet);
```

and now I don't get an error for that part. how do I fix the encoding part for Flash player 11 and AIR 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `stringify` method instead of encode for Flash 11 or greater.

```
stringify(value:Object, replacer:* = null, space:* = null):String
```

You can see more information in the AS3 livedocs for stringify.